# ¿Cómo puedo obtener los valores de multiple checkbox y comprobarlo en una sentencia switch?

Tags: php, variables, depuración

En una práctica me piden que haga operaciones con dos números, y solo con switch-case, además no puedo usar funciones que no sean las predefinidas de PHP.

He de poder seleccionar 2 o más opciones a la vez, pero en la opción de multiplicar me da error y las demás no las pone juntas.

**HTML**:

```
<form name="Formulario" method="post" action="ejercicio4.php">
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td>Introduce elprimer número (a): <input type="number" name="numa" required/>      Introduce el segundo número (b): <input type="number" name="numb" required>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        Operaciones a realizar
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                    <input type="checkbox" name="operacion" value="1">Obtener la potencia de a elevado a b <br/>
                    <input type="checkbox" name="operacion2" value="2">Obtener el producto de a por b<br/>
                    <input type="checkbox" name="operacion3" value="3">Obtener la divisón de a entre b<br/>
                    <input type="checkbox" name="operacion4" value="4">Obtener el resto de la divisón de a entre b<br/>
                    <input type="checkbox" name="operacion5" value="5">Obtener el mayor de a y b<br/>
                    </td>
                    <tr>
                        <td><input type="submit" name="Enviar">
                        <input type="reset" name="Reestablecer">
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </tr>
            </table>
```

**PHP:**

```
<?php
$a = $_POST['numa'];
$b = $_POST['numb'];
$operacion = $_POST['operacion'];
$operacion2 = $_POST['operacion2'];
$operacion3 = $_POST['operacion3'];
$operacion4 = $_POST['operacion4'];
$operacion5 = $_POST['operacion5'];
//Ejercicio
echo "Los números introducidos son: $a y $b <br/>";
//Para ocultar los mensajes de error les asigno un valor a aquellas variables vacías
if (empty($operacion)) {
    $operacion = 0;
}
elseif (empty($operacion2)) {
    $operacion2 = 0;
}
elseif (empty($operacion3)) {
    $operacion3 = 0;
}
elseif (empty($operacion4)) {
    $operacion4 = 0;
}
elseif (empty($operacion5)) {
    $operacion5 = 0;
}
else{
    echo "Has marcadado todas las operaciones";
}
switch ($operacion) {
    case '1':
        $pot= pow($a,$b);
        echo "El resultado es $pot <br/>";
        break;

    default:
        echo "No has seleccionado la opción 1<br/>";
        break;
}
switch ($operacion2) {
    case '2':
        $prod = $a*$b;
        echo "El resultado es $prod <br/>";
        break;

    default:
        echo "No has seleccionado la opción 2 <br/>";
        break;
}switch ($operacion3) {
    case '3':
        $div= $a/$b;
        echo "El resultado es $div <br/>";
        break;

    default:
        echo "No has seleccionado la opción 3";
        break;
}switch ($operacion4) {
    case '4':
        $rest = $a%$b;
        echo "El resultado es $rest <br/>";
        break;

    default:
        echo "No has seleccionado la opción 4 <br/>";
        break;
}switch ($operacion5) {
    case '5':
        if ($a == $b) {
            echo "Los números son iguales";
        }
        elseif ($a > $b) {
            echo "$a es mayor";
        }
        else{
            echo "$a es menor";
        }
        break;

    default:
        echo "No has seleccionado la opción 5 <br/>";
        break;
}
?>
```

Sin embargo, aunque las operaciones las hace bien, me da error:

```
Notice: Undefined index: operacion in /opt/lampp/htdocs/practica1/ejercicio4.php on line 4

Notice: Undefined index: operacion3 in /opt/lampp/htdocs/practica1/ejercicio4.php on line 6

Notice: Undefined index: operacion4 in /opt/lampp/htdocs/practica1/ejercicio4.php on line 7

Notice: Undefined index: operacion5 in /opt/lampp/htdocs/practica1/ejercicio4.php on line 8
```

Comment: ¿Cuál es el error?

Comment: El producto no me lo hace, y no admite varias entradas a la vez

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Para sacar a multiples `checkbox` los valores, deberías iniciarlo como array's agregando `[]` (corchetes) al final de los nombres en los atributos `name`, por ejemplo:

```
                                 <!-- ↓ corchetes --> 
<input type="checkbox" name="operacion[]" value="1">Obtener la potencia de a elevado a b <br/>
<input type="checkbox" name="operacion[]" value="2">Obtener el producto de a por b<br/>
<input type="checkbox" name="operacion[]" value="3">Obtener la divisón de a entre b<br/>
```

Una vez hecho esto puedes sacar los valores del array `$_POST['operacion'][]`:

```
// checkbox #1 marcado
echo $_POST['operacion'][0]; // salida: "1"
```

Ahora podemos sacar todos los valores que recibimos del `checkbox` con un [foreach()](http://php.net/manual/es/control-structures.foreach.php):

```
$operaciones = $_POST['operacion'];
foreach($operaciones as $operacion){
   echo $operacion;
}
```

Si ningún `checkbox` está marcado y no lo compruebas antes de recorrer en el `foreach()` te saldrá un falló, lo evitamos simplemente si lo comprobamos con [isset()](http://php.net/manual/es/function.isset.php) anteriormente:

```
$operaciones = $_POST['operacion'];

if (isset($operaciones) {

    foreach($operaciones as $operacion){
        echo $operacion;
    }
}
```

Ya lo tenemos casi listo, falta el [switch](http://php.net/manual/es/control-structures.switch.php)!

En el `switch` lo que hacemos, es simplemente comprobar los valores que nos brinde el `foreach()`, (te dejo aquí ya toda la solución):

```
<?php
$a = (int)$_POST['numa'];
$b = (int)$_POST['numb'];

$operaciones = (int)$_POST['operacion'];

echo "Los números introducidos son: $a y $b <br>";

if (isset($operaciones)) {

    foreach($operaciones as $operacion){

        switch ($operacion) {

            case 1:
                $pot = pow($a, $b);
                echo "El resultado es $pot <br>";
                break;
            case 2:         
                $prod = $a * $b;
                echo "El resultado es $prod <br>";
                break;
            case 3:
                $div = $a / $b;
                echo "El resultado es $div <br>";
                break;
            case 4:
                $res = $a % $b;
                echo "El resto es $res <br>";
                break;
            case 5:
                echo $a > $b ? "a = $a es mayor que b = $b" 
                             : ($a < $b ? "a = $a es menor que b = $b" 
                             : "Son iguales a = $a y b = $b");
                break;
            default:
                echo "Ups..algo no ha ido bien!";
        }
    }
}
```

HTML:

```
<form name="Formulario" method="post" action="ejercicio4.php">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>
                Introduce elprimer número (a): 
                <input type="number" name="numa" required>
                <br>
                Introduce el segundo número (b):
                <input type="number" name="numb" required>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                Operaciones a realizar
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <input type="checkbox" name="operacion[]" value="1">
                Obtener la potencia de a elevado a b 
                <br/>
                <input type="checkbox" name="operacion[]" value="2">
                Obtener el producto de a por b
                <br/>
                <input type="checkbox" name="operacion[]" value="3">
                Obtener la divisón de a entre b
                <br/>
                <input type="checkbox" name="operacion[]" value="4">
                Obtener el resto de la divisón de a entre b
                <br/>
                <input type="checkbox" name="operacion[]" value="5">
                Obtener el mayor de a y b
                <br/>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <input type="submit" name="Enviar">
                <input type="reset" name="Reestablecer">
            </td>
        </tr>   
    </table>
</form>
```

Comment: No me funciona: me da error en el foreach

Comment: Decía que no se esperaba lo que hay en esa línea, ahora lo pruebo:

Comment: El error de ser deficiente y copiar mal, pero eso no puedes arreglarlo. Muchas gracias por tu atención

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php

$a = $_POST['numa'];
$b = $_POST['numb'];

echo "Los números introducidos son: $a y $b <br/>";
switch (true) {
    case isset($_POST['operacion']):
        $pot = pow($a, $b);
        echo "El resultado es $pot <br/>";
    case isset($_POST['operacion2']):
        $prod = $a*$b;
        echo "El resultado es $prod <br/>";
    case isset($_POST['operacion3']):
        $div = $a/$b;
        echo "El resultado es $div <br/>";
    case isset($_POST['operacion4'] ):
        $res = $a%$b;
        echo "El resto es $res <br/>";
    case isset($_POST['operacion5'] ):
        if ($a == $b) {
            echo "$a y $b";
        } elseif ($a < $b) {
            echo "$a es menor";
        } else{
            echo "$b es mayor";
        }
}

?>
```

Comment: Te ha faltado $a

Comment: Gracias ras212, lo he corregido.

Comment: no funciona, da error con el array

Comment: Perdón, había pensado que obtenías la operación desde un select múltiple, no me dí cuenta que habias puesto unos cuantos checkbox. Ahora sí que funciona.

Comment: Sigue dando error